# Base64 Encoding Delphi

Tags: php, delphi, encoding, base64

I'm making a `Delphi` application and I'm trying to encode with base64 encoding stream and I made two functions:

```
function EncodedInputParams(input: TStringStream): string;
var
  output: TStringStream;
  encoder: TIdEncoderMIME;
begin
  input.Encoding.UTF8;
  input.Position := 0;
  output := TStringStream.Create;

  try
    encoder := TIdEncoderMIME.Create(nil);
    encoder.Encode(input, output);
    output.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    Result := output.DataString;
  finally
    output.Free;
  end;
end;

function SecondEncoding(input: TStringStream): string;
var
  output: TStringStream;
  midRes: string;
begin
  input.Encoding.UTF8;
  input.Position := 0;
  output := TStringStream.Create;

  try
    EncodeStream(input, output);
    output.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
    midRes := output.DataString;
    midRes := StringReplace(midRes, #13#10, EmptyStr, [rfReplaceAll]);
    result := midRes;
  finally
    output.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Functions are working fine but the problem is that these solutions return different string than a string encoded same way in PHP: http://www.tools4noobs.com/online_php_functions/base64_encode/ . 
Any ideas how to rewrite one of the function to return string like one written in PHP.

Comment: Please include examples of both variants so that we know what this difference is

Comment: Please edit the question rather than adding comments. I'm also sceptical of the fact that you are encoding text. You've not stated how the text is represented. ASCII? UTF-8? Or what. Remember that base64 encodes byte arrays to text. A great many people fail to understand that detail and its implications.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan thank you for the advice. When I add this line: input.Encoding.UTF8; and now it works fine :)

Comment: Good. That makes sense. When base64 encoding text you must first of all convert to a byte array using a well-defined text encoding. UTF-8 is usually a good choice. Once you have that byte array it should be plain sailing.